# Importing Proto File to another ProtoFile in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I am quite new to Protocol Buffers.

I noticed that the grpc `proto-loader` module requires just a single proto definition file to load, so I have loaded it in my code as below:

```
const PROTO_PATH = `${path.resolve(__dirname, '..')}${path.sep}protos${path.sep}index.proto`;
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
});

let indexProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).index;
```

Now my `index.proto` file is referencing another proto file
as below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package index;

import public "location_updater.proto";
```

And my `location_updater.proto` is defined as below

```
syntax = "proto3";

package location_updater;

service LocationUpdater{
    rpc updateLocation(Location) returns LocationUpdateResponse{}
}

message Location{
    string apiKey = 1;
    string updateTarget = 2;
    double longitude = 3;
    double latitude = 4;
}

message LocationUpdateResponse{
    int32 statusCode = 1;
}
```

When I do the following:

```
 let grpcServer = new grpc.Server();
        grpcServer.addService(indexProto.location_updater.LocationUpdater.service, {

        });
```

I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'LocationUpdater' of undefined`

If I move the content of  the `location_updater.proto` into to the `index.proto` file it works, but I don't want that behavior as I would be working with many different proto files for different business logic.

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to go about this?.

Thanks in anticipation for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `includeDirs` option to include directories in the search paths, so that the proto loader library knows how to find the imported files. Those directories should be the ones that the `import` paths are relative to.

In this situation, assuming that `location_updater.proto` is in the same directory as `index.proto`, the `includeDirs` option should be an array containing the single path `__dirname/../protos`. Those directories can also be used to search for the main file, so you can pass a proto path that is just `index.proto`.